# Excel VBA Function needs to receive either a hardcoded ParamArray list or Range

Tags: excel, vba

```
Function AndSearch1(ByRef target As Range, ParamArray searchList() As Variant) As Boolean
    'AND Boolean logic search using a hardcoded list
    Dim i As Long
    For Each cell In searchList
        i = InStr(target.Value, cell): If i = 0 Then AndSearch1 = False: Exit Function
    Next
    AndSearch1 = True
End Function

Function AndSearch2(ByRef target As Range, ByRef searchList As Range) As Boolean
    'AND Boolean logic search using a list Range
    Dim i As Long
    For Each cell In searchList
        i = InStr(target.Value, cell): If i = 0 Then AndSearch2 = False: Exit Function
    Next
    AndSearch2 = True
End Function
```

The following will work fine within Excel:

```
=AndSearch1(A1,"red","white","blue")
```

where red, white and blue are within cells B1:B3

```
=AndSearch2(A1,B1:B3)
```

But is it possible to code a single AndSearch function so that it can receive either the hardcoded strings or the Range?

Comment: This would be better suited to [CodeReview.se]

Comment: @mark  your Q is not off topic on SO, so please don't feel you have to move it to CR.  But if you do, please read their help first  they have different rules

Comment: BTW a simple array formula will do this without the need for vba: `=AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"red","white","blue"},A1)))` and `=AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1:B3,A1)))` confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: This is very interesting, I've not seen ISNUMBER() used with AND with multiple search text. I notice this also works with using OR, XOR and NOT operators in place of the AND operator. Thanks for sharing this.

Comment: I want to add to my comment: use of the NOT operator did not provide results that I could figure out.  The AND operator is True when ALL of the search words are found; OR operator is True for 1 or more matches; XOR was True for an odd number of matches. If you want to check for None (no matches) then a NOT of the OR formula above would handle this, and the NOT of the XOR formula would provide True for even numbered matches.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, VBA does not have anything like function/method overloads.

I have not tested this, but I think it should work for the two specific cases (*either* a paramarray of string literal, or a single range object):

```
Function AndSearch1(ByRef target As Range, ParamArray searchList() As Variant) As Boolean
    'AND Boolean logic search using a hardcoded list
    Dim i As Long
    Dim myArray as Variant
    myArray = searchList
    If UBound(searchList) = 0 Then
        If TypeName(searchList(0)) = "Range" Then
             If searchList(0).Rows.Count = 1 and searchList(0).Columns.Count > 1 Then
                 myArray = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(searchList(0).Value))
             ElseIf searchList(0).Rows.Count > 1 and searchList(0).Columns.Count = 1 Then
                 myArray = searchList(0).Value
             Else
                 'you'd need additional logic to handle 2-dimensional ranges
             End If             
        End If
    End If
    For Each cell In myArray # iterate the myArray instead of the searchList
```

NOTE: I don't think this will work (but could be revised to handle different edge cases) if you pass a `ParamArray` of ranges, like:

```
=AndSearch1("A1:B1","C2:C15")
```

Nor if it's a 2-dimensional range.

```
=AndSearch1("A1:D4")
```

But it could be adapted for those cases, the idea is to just take *whatever* argument(s) the function receives, and assign them to an appropriately iterable one-dimensional Variant.